# Append to object variable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ultimately, I want to create an object:

```
newData = {
    column1: "",
    column2: "",
    column3: "",
    ...
    columnN: ""
}
```

column names come from another array of objects, which is essentially a global variable tableColumns:

```
tableColumns = [
    {headerName: "column1", field: "c1", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column2", field: "c2", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column3", field: "c3", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column4", field: "c4", editable: false}
]
```

Without any hard coding, how can I dynamically create newData via looping through this.tableColumns?

Comment: What will be the value of `column1`, `column2` ... in `newData` object? Are they empty or null?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal either is ok for me. This newData will be used to insert a new empty row in a table. So I don't care.

Comment: Ok I have posted a answer for that. You can set with any value you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `tableColumns` and set the value of `headerName` key as the key of `newData` object:

```js
var tableColumns = [
    {headerName: "column1", field: "c1", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column2", field: "c2", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column3", field: "c3", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column4", field: "c4", editable: false}
];

var newData = {};

tableColumns.forEach((col)=>{
  newData[col.headerName] = '';
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: @Henrix glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your items and dynamically assign properties based on your `headerName` column

```js
const tableColumns = [
    {headerName: "column1", field: "c1", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column2", field: "c2", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column3", field: "c3", editable: false},
    {headerName: "column4", field: "c4", editable: false}
];

const result = {};

tableColumns.forEach(item => {
  result[item.headerName] = item.field;
});

console.log(result);
```